# Should we give the guest user profile the "view encrypted data" permission?

Tags: security, permission-sets, ssl, crypto, field-level-security

We've developed native VF/Apex code that allows us to send a link to a customer and have them securely view a PDF of their contract (contract is a VF page generated using data from fields in their record).  That contract contains some fields we'd like to encrypt in our instance, however, if we encrypt the fields, they won't be able to view the link/PDF correctly unless we give the guest user the "view encrypted data" permission set.

That just seems like a bad idea - what are the risks of doing that? anyone have any suggested workarounds?

I'm considering using the Crypto class but would prefer not to, if possible.  Also don't want to use a 3rd party app.